# How to add each number to list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have following variable:

```
number = "456367"
```

I need to add it to list by one number, like this:

```
list = [['4', '5', '6', '3', '6', '7']]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you really want a `[['4', '5', '6', '3', '6', '7']]` as your return value, as opposed to a `['4', '5', '6', '3', '6', '7']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a string is [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable), pass it to the [list](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#func-list) constructor:

```
>>> list("456367")
['4', '5', '6', '3', '6', '7']
```

Which is why you would not want to name the result `list` because you would stomp on the name of that convenient function ;-)

---

If you really want `[['4', '5', '6', '3', '6', '7']]` vs just a list of characters:

```
>>> s="456367"
>>> map(list, zip(*s))
[['4', '5', '6', '3', '6', '7']]
```

Or,

```
>>> [list(s)]
[['4', '5', '6', '3', '6', '7']]
```

But I am assuming with the first answer that the extra brackets were a typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> number = "456367"
>>> [char for char in number]
['4', '5', '6', '3', '6', '7']
```